# Appending to Json Array in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am working with backbone.js as front end that receives a json result from controller like this

```
def index
    myEntry = Entry.all
    respond_with myEntry.to_json()
end
```

The resulting json arrays is collection of objects as follows

```
0:Object
  id:1
  name:matz
1:object
  id:2
  name: hilary
```

Now i have for each name an extra tag field that is stored using [act-as-taggable-on gem](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on). To access the tag of any entry i would have to use **Entry.find(1).tag_list.**
I would like to append the result of each tag to its respective object from above, to get result something like this

```
0:Object
  id:1
  name:matz
  tag:friend,rich
1:object
  id:2
  name: hilary
  tag:intelligent
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
render json: User.all.to_json(include: :tags)
```

or alternatively (just tag names):

```
render json: User.all.to_json(methods: :tag_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

Perfect answer from @dimakura. But if you wanted to include something to your json array that was somehow not directly connected to your result, or for more complex reasons, here is another way

- Create an empty array
- Loop through your result array

  - In each of loop append to the array your required hash value
- Return array converted into json

Example Code

```
myEntry = Entry.all
myhash = []
myEntry.each do |index|
   myhash << {name: index.name,tag_list: index.tag_list}
end

respond_with myhash.to_json
```